# How to get the difference between DateTime fields in Apex trigger

Tags: salesforce, apex

I have two DateTime fields **ApprovedAt**, **SubmittedAt**.

What I am trying to do is I would like to calculate turn around time by using this -> (ApprovedAt - SubmittedAt)

How we can do that in APex trigger? And what should be the type of field **TurnAroundTime** ?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get number of days from

```
SubmittedAt - ApprovedAt
```

and it is of type Integer. You can convert it to hours , minutes or whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use a Long instead.

```
Long approvedAt = fieldnameA__c.getTime();
Long submittedAt = fieldnameB__c.getTime();

Long milliseconds = submittedAt - approvedAt;
Long seconds = milliseconds / 1000;
Long minutes = seconds / 60;
Long hours = minutes / 60;
Long days = hours / 24;
```